# Can't drag map over view with GONE visibility

Tags: android, android-layout, android-maps-v2

I have set up google map and I have a view (a `ConstraintLayout` with a height of `150dp`) that slides up and gets `visibility(View.VISIBLE)` on the bottom of the screen when i click a marker on the map.

The problem is that when I deselect the marker and set the view as `GONE`, I can't use that part of the screen to drag the map.

I tried also to set `focusable` and `clickable` to `false`, but still nothing.

Any idea?
Thank you!

Comment: Have you solve this? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Call bringToFront() on the maps view.

```
map.bringToFront();
```

Other thing that could help is to put the maps view At the end of the XML.

Comment: sorry for the delayed response. map does not have that method, and if i put the map view at the end then my layout won't show... thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve this!

The problem was with the animation.

Set the **hide** animation to have `setFillAfter(false)`

Something like this:

```java
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),R.anim.slide_down);
animation.setDuration(150);
animation.setFillAfter(false);   // <--- This makes the difference for me
animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        theLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    }
});
theLayout.startAnimation(animation);
```

Also I do have `focusable`, `focusableInTouchMode` and `clickable` set to **true** on that layout and other inner layouts.

#### OPTION 2

Also another possibility would be to change the elevation of that layout so it would have a greater value than the map's elevation when you what to show it and a lower when you hide it.

The problem of this is that it won't work on lower api devices